# What site for asking about charts?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, graphs

So far, I have known four sites to ask about charts: Graphic Design, Cross Validated, Academia and User Experience. Except Graphic Design which is more obviously that it is about the graphic, not the content, I can't distinguish the differences in the other three in asking about charts. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Different aspects of charts:

- Graphic Design - for visual impact of a chart
- Cross Validated - for the calculations / statistics behind the chart
- User Experience - for the User Experience (UX) of the chart (may overlap somewhat with Graphic Design)
- Academia - huh? Perhaps about charts within academia? How they should be presented and what kinds of data they should have. I would say - specific to the academic world.

And what about Stack Overflow? When developing chart display? Showing charts in a program on the web?

Or Super User - for charting Excel or other spreadsheet info?

In short - look at the topic of the site. What they are **about**. If they have charts there - it is a **subset** of the main topic.

Comment: Let's say about this question about [which chart should be used](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/124316/whats-a-good-way-to-represent-a-complex-timeline). It was initiated ask in GD, but then I recommended the OP to ask it in Cross Validated. The mod accepted his proposal of migration. But you say that Cross Validated is for the calculation and statistics behind the chart, and I don't think it asked about statistics or calculation. To add more, I have asked [some chart questions](http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/59765/ooker) in Cross Validated about, erm, graphic designs?

Comment: There is some amount of overlap - but it really is about the focus of your question. In this case, I would say UX might fit best. You can always post on a site specific meta to ask if they accept that kind of question (or how to ask such a question so it is suitable there).

Comment: The metas, right. Thank you so much.

Comment: I think Academia would be about which type of charts to use depending on the context of the content. For example, using a 3d chart for a younger audience may be overkill and should be broken into multiple 2d charts. In order words, I think "perhaps charts within academia" is correct.

Comment: Note that *data-vizualization* questions are explicitly listed as on topic on Cross-Validated, so it's not merely for calculation behind the graphics -- questions about definitions, details or effectiveness of the statistical graphic itself (for example) are more broadly on topic there.

Answer (score 1):

I would tend to think that https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ is another valid place, as plotting is one of the main aspects of data science. Most questions on charts should be on-topic there (e.g., see tag https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visualization). More generally, all CV questions are on-topic on DS, which [isn't ideal](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2026/12359)...

Comment: can you tell the difference between Data Science and other sites, like Oded above did?

Comment: @Ooker I believe most questions on charts should be on-topic there, including all types Oded mentioned. Some rarer questions like issues with using chart tools might be better asked on SU, SO, TeX, or OS-specific SE. Softrecs when looking for new tools. Etc etc. Charts are a vast topic.

Comment: I think you can add that into your answer

Comment: There isn't even a "chart" tag at DS.  I'm skeptical about whether or not I should post there...

Comment: @Scott http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visualization